# Defining $\mathbb{C}$ without defining $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: logic, field-theory

To define $\mathbb{R}$, one approach is to start with $\mathbb{N}$ and then systematically introduce $\mathbb{Z},$ $\mathbb{Q}$, and then $\mathbb{R}$. Alternatively, we define $\mathbb{R}$ using its axiomatic definition that it is a complete ordered field. And then, we can construct $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ within $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, $\mathbb{C}$ is introduced in the first way, by making $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a field. Can we follow the latter approach of defining $\mathbb{C}$ axiomatically, and then construct $\mathbb{R}$ inside it?

Comment: The (upward) Lowenheim Skolem theorem says that no axiomatization that yields $ \mathbb C $ up to isomorphism will be first order, since the theorem states that if it were first order there would be arbitrarily large models of it.

Comment: @user571438 To be fair, the same holds for $\mathbb{R}$, and the OP seems happy with the "complete ordered field" axiomatization, so that's probably not an issue here.

Comment: Incidentally, a similar issue crops up in the other half of the question: $\mathbb{C}$ is much model-theoretically simpler than $\mathbb{R}$ (no, that's not a typo!), so any way of constructing $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{C}$ will be "logically expensive."

Comment: @NoahSchweber Can you elaborate on what you mean by "model-theoretically simpler"?

Comment: @user571438 There are various notions of "tameness" in model theory, and several of them hold of (the theory of) $\mathbb{C}$ but not of (the theory of) $\mathbb{R}$ (e.g. stability). This isn't to say that $\mathbb{R}$ itself isn't tame in any model-theoretic sense (it is e.g. $o$-minimal) but $\mathbb{C}$ is much more tame.

Comment: One _could_ do something like define $\mathbb C$ as the completion of $\mathbb Q[X]/(X^2+1)$ (under such-and-such metric, extending $+$ and $\times$ by continuity) and then define $\mathbb R$ as the unique topologically closed proper subfield of $\mathbb C$. But that doesn't really feel enlightening ...

Comment: This will be a construction similar to the first way of extending from $\mathbb{Q}.$ The requirement is the other alternative.

Comment: I don't think your question makes sense: what do you mean by "latter approach" and "defining $\Bbb{C}$ axiomatically"? Your comment doesn't help to clarify this. Note that $\Bbb{R}$ is not definable as a subfield of $\Bbb{C}$ in the language of rings/fields.

Answer (score 2):

You may find [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2688967) helpful.

However, I disagree with some of the philosophy embedded in your question. You write:

> Alternatively, we define R using its axiomatic definition that it is a complete ordered field. And then, we can construct N, Z and Q within R.

With a small caveat, this isn't really correct, insofar as you can't really "construct things axiomatically" - that's not how math works. In particular, to define a thing, you should either:

1. Construct it out of things that have already known to exist, or
2. Characterize it by some constraints **and then prove there is a unique thing satisfying those constraints.**

Notice the boldface portion above. Suppose you want define $\mathbb{R}$ axiomatically - fine, but you need to prove that there's a unique thing up to isomorphism satisfying your definition. Uniqueness should be easy enough. But how would you prove existence? Well, you'd probably begin by constructing $\mathbb{N}$, and then building your way up to $\mathbb{Q}$ and taking a completion. So this isn't really an alternative. Of course, you could do things differently. For example, you could start of by constructing the surreal numbers recursively, and then obtain $\mathbb{R}$ as a subset of those - that would be a different way of constructing $\mathbb{R}$. But at the end of the day, you still haven't "constructed $\mathbb{R}$ axiomatically" - you've just constructed it in a different way.

The caveat I mentioned earlier is that you can replace the axiom of infinity in ZFC with an axiom that instead posits the existence of a real numbers object, thereby obtaining a new system, let's call it ZFCR. It seems likely that ZFCR is equivalent to ZFC, for the reasons you give.

Comment: Indeed,existence of $\mathbb{R}$ defined as a complete ordered field requires building it through $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}.$ But we know, existence of $\N$ defined via Peano's axioms is to be assumed. Instead, in the `latter' approach, we posit the existence of $\R$.

Comment: @Arvind, you're looking for the commands \mathbb{N} and \mathbb{R}. I disagree that "the existence of $\mathbb{N}$ defined via Peano's axioms is to be assumed." If you look at the ZFC axioms the axiom of infinite says something very specific, and it's not Peano's axioms.

Comment: Note that in the quoted statement, Arvind only says that $\Bbb N, \Bbb Z, \Bbb Q$ are constructed *within* $\Bbb R$. I.e., at this point one simply considers $\Bbb R$ as an already existing objects, and you are identifying which subsets of it are to be the other 3 sets. It is true that you need to prove that there is a complete ordered field, and all ordered fields are isomorphic to it. But defining $\Bbb R$ axiomatically simply means one is picking an otherwise undistinguished object with these properties. Thus $\Bbb R$ has nothing unnecessary for R-ness, unlike constructed versions.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Perhaps the unique algebraically and topologically complete partially ordered field of characteristic $0$?</s>

However, I am not sure it is true - dropping from ordered to partially ordered opens up a lot of freedom that may allow other contenders.

I am modifying this answer (the idea above is highly doubtful) to address Arvind's questions in the July 6 comment below.

Here is an outline of one approach to prove that $\Bbb C$ is, up to isomorphism, the only connected, locally compact topological field of characteristic $0$ which remains connected when $0$ is removed. There may be easier approaches, and I have not gone through the steps myself to make sure there are no significant hurdles that I am overlooking, but this is the approach I would try:

Let $\mathscr C$ be a connected, locally compact topological field of characteristic $0$ for which $\mathscr C \setminus \{0\}$ is also connected. We need to show that $\scr C$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb C$ as topological fields.

- Let $\scr N\subset C$ be the smallest set containing $0$ and $1$, and closed under addition. One can inductively define a well ordering on $\scr N$  by the requirement that $n < n + 1$. Using this well-ordering, define an isomorphism of monoids with $\Bbb N$ that also preserves multiplication. (Note that this requires $\scr C$ to be of characteristic $0$ to work.)
- Let $\scr Z$ be the smallest set containing $\scr N$ closed under subtraction. Extend the order on $\scr N$ to $\scr Z$. The order-preserving isomophism of monoids between $\scr N$ and $\Bbb N$ extends to an order-preserving isomorphism of unital rings between $\scr Z$ and $\Bbb Z$.
- Let $\scr Q$ be the smallest field in $\scr C$. Note that it must contain $\scr Z$. Show that the order and isomorphism also extend to $\scr Q$, where the isomorphism is a isomorphism of topological fields.
- Use the continuity of the $+, \cdot$ operators to show that the topology on $\scr Q$ induced by the order is the same as the subspace topology from $\scr C$
- Let $\scr R$ be the closures of $\scr Q$. Show that it is also a field, and the order and isomorphism extend as well. And again that the order topology is the same as the subspace topology. Note that this also shows $\scr R$ is complete, since $\Bbb R$ is.
- Note that $\scr C$ is a vector space over the subfield $\scr R$. Use local compactness at $0$ to prove that the vector space must be finite dimensional.
- Since $\scr R$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R$, we know that $\scr R[x]/(x^2 + 1)$ is algebraicly closed. Hence the only finite dimensional extensions of $\scr R$ have dimension $1$ or $2$. If $\scr C$ has dimension $1$ over $\scr R$, it must be $\scr R$ itself.
- Note that $\scr R \setminus \{0\}$ is disconnected (since it is isomorphic to $\Bbb R$), but $\scr C \setminus \{0\}$ is connected. Therefore $\scr C \ne \scr R$.
- Conclude that $\scr C$ is a two-dimensional extension of $\scr R$, and therefore isomorphic to $\scr R[x]/(x^2 + 1)$, which contains two elements $i$ satisfying $i^2 = -1$. Choose one of them arbitrarily to be "$i$", and use it to extend the isomophism between $\scr R$ and $\Bbb R$ to an isomorphism between $\scr C$ and $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Is there a particular partial ordering on $ \mathbb C $ you're referring to?

Comment: Do you mean to define $\mathbb{C}$ as a field of characteristic 0, which is algebraically closed, and  where every Cauchy sequence converges? And then how to define $\mathbb{R}$ in it? The definition of $\mathbb{R}$ should be defined as we define $\mathbb{N}$ inside $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @user571438 - The partial order I have in mind is obviously $|z|\le |w|$. But this cannot be directly defined until after $|z|$ is defined, which in turn requires defining $\bar z$ (and $\sqrt{z\bar z}$, but that can be gotten around). The thing is, to discuss completeness, you have to define what a "Cauchy sequence" is, which requires at a minimum a topology on the field making the field operations continuous. To get $\Bbb C$, we need its normal topology. On $\Bbb R$ we can get that by simply requiring an order. But without $\Bbb R$ already defined, it is much harder.

Comment: @Arvind - if you have $\Bbb C$, then $\Bbb R$ is identifiable as the smallest closed (topologically) subfield of $\Bbb C$. In fact, the only closed subfields are $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ itself. As I said to user571438, to talk about "Cauchy sequences" requires the topology on $\Bbb C$. I was hoping that perhaps it would be enough to get it from a partial ordering on $\Bbb C$, but I think that isn't strong enough a condition to ensure a unique topology.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair That's not a partial order though. Partial orders have to be antisymmetric, but two complex numbers with the same magnitude need not be equal.

Comment: @user571438 - under the partial order induced by that condition, two non-equal complex numbers of the same magnitude are not comparable. I was indicating the idea, not giving a full definition in a comment where I needed to use the limited space to talk about other things. I was expecting you to fill in the details *appropriately*.

Comment: It should be remarked that $(z,w \mapsto |z| \leq |w|)$ is only a preorder, not a partial order.

Comment: Taking hint from wiki page: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Characterization_as_a_topological_field      we may define $\mathbb{C}$ as the field of characteristic 0 with a topology $\tau$  where $(\mathbb{C},\tau)$ is connected, locally compact, and $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ is connected. (Here, `the' requires some work.) But then can we show the existence of $i$ there? And, that each complex number is in the form $a+b i$ where $a,b$ are devoid (?) of $i$?

Comment: @Arvind - I decided to answer your question in the post itself, since my former suggestion was poor, and even the outline I give is far too long for a comment.

Comment: @goblin - yes. I really should have said $|z| < |w|$, I just didn't think about it because it was just a sideline to what I was trying to say in that comment.

Comment: Thanks Paul Sinclair. The construction works and gives $\mathbb{R}$ inside $\mathbb{C}.$ Perhaps Cauchy completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ is to be seen first.